# Diastereoselectivity in the zinc-mediated Barbier allylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereoselectivity

Penumati & Kommu (2014) report the stereoselective synthesis of (+)-$\alpha$-conhydrine from R-(+)-glyceraldehyde. In their synthesis, the imine **6** underwent a zinc-mediated Barbier allylation to produce secondary amine **7**.

[image]

They explained the preferential formation of the major product **7a** over **7b** via the following Felkin-Ahn model, claiming that the anionic allyl nucleophile approaches the less hindered face. However, it appears to me that there is no significant difference in the steric hindrance posed by each face of the imine group. Hence, I am skeptical if application of the Felkin-Ahn model here is appropriate and whether it does give the correct predicted major product. I thought of using the chelation model, since certainly there is a possibility $\ce {Zn^2+}$ can be involved, but I realised that it doesn't seem to be appropriate as well, or at least that is what appears to be the case for me.

[image]

**Reference**

Penumati, N. R.; Kommu, N. Stereoselective Synthesis of (+)-$\alpha$-Conhydrine from R-(+)-Glyceraldehyde. *Organic Chemistry International*, **2014**. doi: [10.1155/2014/982716](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/oci/2014/982716/)

Comment: The Felkin-Anh model isn't about which "face" is less hindered (true, the nucleophile always attacks opposite $R_L$, but you can just rotate the bond until $R_L$ is on the *other* side of the carbonyl). It's the positions of $R_M$ and $R_S$ that dictate the stereoselectivity, and when the nucleophile attacks via the Burgi-Dunitz angle, you want $R_S$ to be in its way and not $R_M$. The chelation model would give you the wrong diastereomer. FWIW, that journal doesn't look particularly reliable...

Comment: @orthocresol Actually, I don't even think that the above diagram depicts the Felkin-Ahn model... It does not match my understanding, i.e. what I've read from Claydens. Indeed, it is rather dubious... How would you rationalise such stereoselectivity then?

Comment: Polar Felkin-Anh might be appropriate here: the C-O bond takes the place of the 'large' substituent, which would give you the correct stereochemistry. That would be my best guess, but no guarantees...

Comment: @orthocresol I have tried the polar Felkin-Ahn approach and it does not seem to predict a convincing result that is consistent with the above stereochemistry. Perhaps, you could illustrate what you meant in an answer.

Comment: @orthocresol I have recently read about the evolution of stereochemical models used to predict the stereochemical outcomes of particular reactions. It seems to me that no one model suggested can be universally applied... Do you have any thoughts as to which is the closest model to one that can be universally applied? (I would consider this so-called "polar Felkin-Ahn" and the Felkin-Ahn based on sterics as the same model)